# Install Ubuntu on a second disk while booted into ubuntu from a first disk

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

I want to install a newer Ubuntu on a new disk, but I don't want to take the machine down for the duration of the installation.

Specifically, I would like to install 18.04 on the new disk while the machine is running 16.04 from the old disk, and only when the new installation is complete do I want to reboot the machine.

No set of query terms I've tried have come up with this question, so...

Can this be done, or is one forced to install Ubuntu only when booted into the install DVD or USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

[Instructions from the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux)

Assuming that `/dev/sdb` is the *target* disk of the new installation

Overall:

1. `sudo apt get install debootstrap`
2. `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` or use `gparted` or another partition editor to create a primary partition with an `ext4` file system on it
3. `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`
4. `sudo mkdir /mnt/installer`
5. `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/installer`
6. `sudo debootstrap bionic /mnt/installer`
7. `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/installer/dev`
8. `sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/installer/dev/pts`
9. `sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/installer/proc`
10. `sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/installer/sys`
11. `sudo chroot /mnt/installer`
12. **You are no chrooted and need to stay in this terminal**
13. If you have a language preference see the Wiki article to set that now
14. `dpkg-reconfigure -f non-interactive tzdata`
15. `apt-get update`
16. `apt-get install language-pack-en-base`
17. `apt-get upgrade`
18. `apt-get install mdadm lvm2`
19. `apt-get install grub-pc linux-image`
20. `adduser <username>`
21. `gpasswd -a <username> sudo`
22. `passwd` (set a root password)
23. `echo "/dev/sda1 / ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1" >> /etc/fstab`
24. `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-standard`
25. `exit`
26. **You are no longer chrooted**
27. `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Kristopher, thanks very much.  Trying that right now...

Comment: In case anyone else looks here, some things to note: (1)  dpkg-reconfigure -f non-interactive tzdata should not have a '-' in 'noninteractive'.  Also heed the warning in the linked wiki document to get the backport version of debootstrap if you are installing a newer version.  There are various places where the installation procedure complains, but until I am physically at the target machine I won't try rebooting to see whether any Bad Things happened.